# How to download file from SFTP server using download.file in R with credentials

Tags: r, sftp

How do I specify a username and password to download.file, using method curl to download the file sftp://servername.de/filepath/file.xlsx with username user and password pwd?

Comment: you can try `download.file("sftp://servername.de/filepath/file.xlsx", "localFile.xlsx", extra='-k -u "username:password"')`